# Java regex - delete phrase from string if its not beginning of word

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

Example

```
"I'am peter and i'm apetering or fadapetering"
```

Phrase: pet

Result:

```
I'am peter and i'm aering or fadaering"
```

I need to delete phrase for example "pet" if it's not beginning of word!

While using normal regex i'm having trouble 'cause i'm deleting beginning of word too:

```
outs = textOuts.replaceAll("\\w+" + givePhrase, "");
```

Every is on Strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a positive lookbehind for this.

```
String input = "I'am peter and i'm apetering or fadapetering";
System.out.println(
    input
    .replaceAll("(?<=\\w)pet", "")
);
```

**Output**

```
I'am peter and i'm aering or fadaering
```

**Note**

See [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) on **Special constructs (named-capturing and non-capturing)**.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a look behind:

```
outs = textOuts.replaceAll("\\B" + givePhrase, "");
```

The regex expression `\B` means "not a word boundary" (the opposite of `\b` "word boundary").

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<!\\s|^)pet
```

Try this.See demo.Replace by `empty string`.

http://regex101.com/r/gJ4uX1/1